# laravel i want to show count and with there name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

laravel I'm trying to get count row and its value.

model name Result

example THIS DATA STORED IN DATABASCE

```
NAME    SUBJECT        RESULT 
 A        HX            PASS  
 B        HX            FAIL
 C        DX            PASS
 D        DX            PASS
 E        MR            FAIL
```

I want to show value like blade this

in table

```
SUBJECT   PASS    FAIL
  HX       1       1
  DX       2       0
  MR       0       1
```

Comment: You need to write your own logic to achieve that. Inside your blade write a method between php tags and store the results into a variable and then iterate over them to produce desired results.

Comment: @Ahmet Firat Keler
can you help me

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me:

```
$result = Subject::groupBy('subject')
->selectRaw("subject, SUM(IF(result LIKE 'pass', 1, 0) ) as PASS, SUM(IF(result LIKE 'fail', 1, 0) ) as FAIL")
->get();
```

or write your condition in `SUM`:

```
->selectRaw("subject, SUM(result LIKE 'pass') as PASS, SUM(result LIKE 'fail') as FAIL")
```

not: if you use `COUNT` it's not work.

bro if it's possible use Boolean for result (`1` = `'pass'`, `0` = `'fail'`).

if you have any error you can use:

```
->selectRaw("`subject`, SUM(`result` LIKE 'pass') as PASS, SUM(`result` LIKE 'fail') as FAIL")
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: may this work: 

->selectRaw("`subject`, SUM(`result` LIKE 'pass') as PASS, SUM(`result` LIKE 'fail') as FAIL")